# "Communication link failure" using mysql.jdbc after my device goes to sleep mode

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, sleep-mode

I spent several days trying to resolve an error "communication link failure" that arises exclusively after my device enters sleep mode. The error manifests when I perform an action in my app that triggers a database-related action. Strangely, if I return to my app immediately after the device wakes from sleep mode and wait between 20 to 30 seconds before executing a database-related action, the error does not occur but if I don't wait the error occur.

Notably, the error doesn't surface when my device is charging or connected to a PC via USB.

For context, I am currently working for a company and I am developing that app alone. This app is use by factory workers and I can't afford to have users wait 20 seconds every time the device goes into sleep mode.

I'm developing on Java with Android Studio using mysql-connector-java version "5.1.38", my device is also connected to a VPN using OpenVPN Connect.

I tried many things to resolve this issue:

- close and recreate connection on OnPause and OnResume method
- Reconnected before any database action.
- Updated MySQL version.
- Set USB configuration to 'charge'.

No one on the internet looks like troubleshooting the same issue. I have no idea how to solve this issue and I really need to find a solution.

Comment: You shouldn't be using JDBC from Android in the first place, but use a REST API or other form of web API. The obvious solution/workaround to this is to not use a persistent connection, but create connections for a unit of work and close them immediately when done with the unit. But the real solution is to switch to a web-based (REST) service to mediate between your app and the database.